# Spring Boot Actuator configprops endpoint not returning @Value annotated properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing a central console for our IT group to display properties retrieved from Spring Boot Actuator endpoint /configprops for each microservice running in our SOA ecosystem.  I have 2 questions

1. Seems @Value annotated properties to not get returned despite the documentation saying

> **63.7 Discover built-in options for external properties** ....
>   The definitive list comes from searching the source code for @ConfigurationProperties and @Value annotations, as well as the occasional use of RelaxedEnvironment

Looking at ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint.java, looks like it searches only for @ConfigurationProperties annotated classes:

> beans.putAll(context.getBeansWithAnnotation(ConfigurationProperties.class));

2. Is there an easy way to determine *where* the final property value resolved from?  For example:  Did the property get overridden via environment variable? Or, Did it come from the git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 63.7 is trying to say that the only definitive way to discover all properties (since they can be bound in numerous ways) is to search the source code. We try to use `@ConfigurationProperties` whenever possible so that they can be discovered by IDEs and exposed by the actuator. Unfortunately we don't have a way to detect and expose every single property in the report.

There isn't a definitive way to tell where a property came from at the moment. You might be able to look at `getPropertySources()` from `ConfigurableEnvironment`. That will let you iterate `PropertySource` items, and in turn you can check if they are an `EnumerablePropertySource` and get the values. Each `PropertySource` has a `name` which might provide come clues as t what added it.

Comment: Thanks @phillip_webb  for answering.  For the first question, you should consider adding Value annotated variables to ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint.extract().  Seems including Value properties should be part of the report.

Thanks for the pointers on propertySources.  Probably can infer where the value come from with some level of determinism there.   If it works well, perhaps include as another endpoint in actuator along with its tests.